# unset an org-babel property?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

In org-mode, if I set the `:file` header-arg at some point, like all header args, it is inherited at lower levels. I want to avoid duplicating the header-arg all over. In the case of `:session`, the special value `none` is used to not associate the code block with any existing session, it s always a new session. I want the special value for `:file`, which represents *do not write this to a file, but insert it directly as usual*.

```
* set at top header level
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :R :file "abcd.pdf" :exports both :results output graphics
  :END:

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x = seq( from = -2, to = 2, by = 0.1)
plot (x,x^2,col="red", type="l")
#+END_SRC

** lower level header 
# output still goes to abcd.pdf, but I don't want it to, I want it inserted
#+BEGIN_SRC R 
2 + 2
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I followed what you wanted to do, but edited the post to make it clearer.  If I misunderstood what you wanted to do, we can roll back the changes.

Comment: I'll rewrite it. Or maybe it's better to have a new question. Kind of missed the point. This **is specific** to the `:file` header in org-mode.

Comment: Can you not rewrite the :file argument on a block by block basis?

Comment: Rewrite it to what to make it not output?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can override the `PROPERTY` default values on a
block-by-block basis:

```
* CONFIG
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session *R* :results output 

* TESTING
  #+name: data-setup-silently
  #+begin_src R :results silent
    x <- 1:10
  #+end_src

  #+name: results-silently
  #+begin_src R :results silent
     print(x)
  #+end_src

  #+name: results
  #+begin_src R 
     print(x)
  #+end_src
```

Here:

- The `PROPERTY` sets the default `:results` to `output`
- Block 1: set up the data, and override with `silent` to shut up about it
- Block 2: print out the results, but override with `silent` to prevent results from being added to the buffer
- Block 3: default behavior: print out the results to the buffer

Comment: How does this cover the op's case, switching back and forth from file output to buffer?

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this problem is to set up yasnippets with a few different header arguments. It works well as long as you only have a few different options and use only 1 or 2 languages.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you provide a little more detail in your answer to show how to implement it?  For example, please consider posting the snippets you use.

Comment: The question is not how to handle different header arguments, but what arguments can switch output from file to buffer in subsequent blocks.